# Magento 2 EE multi site CyberSource

Tags: payment-methods, payment-gateway, magento-2.1.7, magento-ee

We have Magento 2 EE installation, and we are using native Cybersource extension for Credit Card payment. Each site has it's own base URL (with different domains). In Cybersource we have created different profiles per site, with corresponding response page configuration. On storefront each site can do it's payment well, but when we are trying to do payment from Magento Admin (backend) we are having this error:

*Refused to display 'https://site1_base_url/cybersource/SilentOrder/TokenResponse' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.*

Because admin's and site's (for which we are doing payment) domains are different.

Comment: The issue was resolved. Magento Cloud support provided patch for this. Thanks !!